# Lay the [lie-lay-lain-laid] tag to rest

Tags: discussion, tag-cleaning

The [lie-lay-lain-laid](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lie-lay-lain-laid) tag is just one example of a [tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tense) issue, so everything in it should be retagged to that or something more specific.

Comment: ... what's the point here? Are you asking for the tags to be merged and synonymised?

Comment: @jimsug Preferably merged or deleted :)

Comment: I'd suggest throwing in [tag:confusables] as another option to retag those questions to. (Many of them would presumably use two or three new tags.)

Comment: It's not really about tense, it's about three words with overlapping paradigms which native speakers acquire somewhat inconsistently and are often unable to conjugate in the traditional fashion without checking a reference.

Comment: Lay/lie are irregular verbs that give some native speakers trouble, so I do think there's merit to giving that set their own tag. [Lie-Lay-Lain] and [Lay-Laid-Laid] would be tense tags. There are lots of discussions about it, like http://web.ku.edu/~edit/lie.html which says "But lie and lay seem to give people more difficulty than do all the other irregular verbs combined." Maybe we should do [sit-sat-set] too :)